# React, useRef to find the number of children

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bkjgep?file=index.js)

I just have two div's in a wrapper div.

I need a way of finding out how many div are in the wrapper div or if there is more than one div in the wrapper div.

I was trying to use useRef to reference the wrapper div and then get the children as childNodes but that doesn't seem to work

Is it possible to do this or whats the best way to find out if there is more then one div in the wrapper div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following to achieve it using ref:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState(<div className="block"></div>);
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let innerElements = wrapperRef.current.innerHTML;
    let count = (innerElements.match(/<div/g) || []).length;
    console.log(count);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}>
      <div className='block'></div>
      <div className='block'></div>
      {blocks}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've intentionally taken the declaration of `useState` to top (before ref). Why? Read [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/).
Also, I've added `[]` to simulate `componentDidMount` behaviour.

Having said that, please note that ref is an escape hatch and as a developer you should use it as the last resort.
From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy.

Here is an alternate version without the use of ref:

```
import React, { Component, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const give10Divs = (str) => {
  const output;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    output += str;
  }
  return output;
}

const App = () => {
  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState(
    <>
      <div className="block"></div>
      <div className="block"></div>
      <div className="block"></div>
    </>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    let divCount = 0;
    const INITIAL_DIV_BLOCKS = 2;
    blocks.props.children.map(node => {
      if (node.type === "div")
        divCount += 1;
    })
    console.log("Number of divs are: ", divCount + INITIAL_DIV_BLOCKS);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className='block'></div>
      <div className='block'></div>
      {blocks}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Is there a better way then to find the numbers of div if not to use ref

Comment: Yes, but I need to know first that how will the setBlocks be populated. Will it come as a props and what will be its type? React node, html node or text like `"<div></div>"`.

Comment: They will actually be `"<div></div>"` added to a containing div

Comment: @Knick I don't believe refs are a last resort thing. They are really really useful when you want to maintain state and/or values across different renders.

Comment: @MananJoshi I am quoting the docs. Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I get it what you mean, in that sense it can be used. I was talking about the scenarios where we hold reference to nodes.

Comment: @Iomine I've updated the solution. You cannot initialize is as text so insted I've used React Fragment. This should work for you.

Comment: @Knick I have read them, it says don't overuse refs but the way you have portrayed the use of them it feels almost like an anti-pattern or bad practice. Btw if you are already overusing refs your app should not be using `react` at all.

Comment: @MananJoshi I understand that you might have an inclination to use ref to get things done. But holding reference to nodes should be avoided if possible. And yes, that's why it should be used as a last resort. (hence a bad practice). Still finding trouble then read [this](https://hackernoon.com/refs-in-react-all-you-need-to-know-fb9c9e2aeb81)
        
You downvoting my solution is fine, I'll let the OP decide, anyway I've provided both the working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant but I came across the same problem where I had to reference the number of children of my parent div in order to build a slider.

I used [childElementCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/childElementCount) property on my ref object and it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like the code below to get your desired output

```js
const App = () => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const { childNodes: childDivs } = wrapperRef.current;

    // This will return you how many divs are inside a parent
    const divCount = Object.keys(childDivs).reduce((acc, div) => {
      if (childDivs[div] instanceof HTMLDivElement) acc += 1;
      return acc;
    }, 0);

    if (divCount > 1) {
      // do something with state, etc according to you requirement.
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}>
      <div className="block" />
      <div className="block" />
      {/* {blocks} */}
    </div>
  );
};
```